# How can I skip over certain parts of my php script? (to make my page load faster)

Tags: php, pagination

```
<?php
$rows_per_page = 2;
$cols_per_page = 2;
$image_href = '<a href=/';
$image_links = array('file1/page1>', 'file2/page2>', 'file3/page3>',  
'file4/page4>',   'file5/page5>', 'file6/page6>', 'file6/page6>',  
'file/page7>', 'file/page8>', 'subfile/page9>');
$img_srcs = '<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/imagetitle/';
$images = array();

for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $images[$i] = $i;
}
$image_ending = '.png" height="200" width="200" /></a>';
$image_descriptions = array('<br />something', '<br />description', 
'<br />arbitrary', 'random', '<br />you', '<br />get', '<br />the',  
'<br />idea', '<br />itsdescriptions');  
$total_images = count($images);
$images_per_page = $rows_per_page * $cols_per_page;
$total_images = count($images);
$total_pages = ceil($total_images / $images_per_page);
$current_page = (int) $_GET['page'];
if($current_page<1 || $current_page>$total_pages)
{
    $current_page = 1;
}

//Get records for the current page
$page_image_links = array_splice($image_links, ($current_page-1)*$images_per_page, $images_per_page);
$page_images = array_splice($images, ($current_page-1)*$images_per_page, $images_per_page);
$page_image_descriptions = array_splice($image_descriptions, ($current_page-1)*$images_per_page, $images_per_page);
$slots = "<table border=\"1\">";
for($row=0; $row<$rows_per_page; $row++)
{
    $slots .= "<tr>";
    for($col=0; $col<$cols_per_page; $col++)
    {
        $imgIdx = ($row * $rows_per_page) + $col;
        $img = (isset($page_images[$imgIdx])) ? "{$image_href}{$page_image_links[$imgIdx]}{$img_srcs}{$page_images[$imgIdx]}{$image_ending}{$page_image_descriptions[$imgIdx]}" : '&nbsp;';
        $slots .= "<td>$img</td>";
    }
    $slots .= "</tr>";
}
$slots .= "</table>";

//Create pagination links
$first = "First";
$prev  = "Prev";
$next  = "Next";
$last  = "Last";
if($current_page>1)
{
    $prevPage = $current_page - 1;
    $first = "<a href=\"blah.php?page=1\">First</a>";
    $prev  = "<a href=\"blah.php?page={$prevPage}\">Prev</a>";
}
if($current_page<$total_pages)
{
    $nextPage = $current_page + 1;
    $next = "<a href=\"blah.php?page={$nextPage}\">Next</a>";
    $last = "<a href=\"blah.php?page={$total_pages}\">Last</a>";
}

?>
<html>
<title></title>
<body>
<h2>Here are the records for page <?php echo $current_page; ?></h2>
  <ul>
    <?php echo $slots; ?>
  </ul>
Page <?php echo $current_page; ?> of <?php echo $total_pages; ?>
<br />
<?php echo "{$first} | {$prev} | {$next} | {$last}"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically this code above makes it easy to put up images and their links. For now, I don't have that many images, so the page runs super fast. However, I'm thinking in the long run. If I have say, 10,000 images, it's gonna take a long time to process each paginated page, as I would have $image_links of file1/page1 up to file10000/page10000, and 10000 different image descriptions! Is there a way to stop the web browser from reading, or skip, certain parts of the script (the $image_links and $image_descriptions in my case)? That way, it won't need to read through all 10000 $image_links and $image_descriptions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What people usually do in this kind of a situation is to store a record of each image in a database. That way you don't have to create the whole list of images each time. So you would only retrieve the images for the page that a user is currently viewing.

## Caching

You can also cache your results. There are all sorts of methods, classes and libraries to do that, but it basically involves doing something like this:

```
$cache_key = 'cache-page-'.$pagenumer.'.cache';
if (!file_exists($cache_key)) {

    ob_start();
    // all your code comes here - to make it very
    // fast, you can do an include() here on the other file
    include 'the-rest-of-your-code-example.php';
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    $fp = fopen($cache_key, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $output);
    fclose($fp);

} else {
    $output = file_get_contents($cache_key);
}

// And finally echo the content
echo $output;
```

Comment: Doesn't that seem obsessive though? It doesn't seem like what I'm doing requires enough to warrant the use of a database.

Comment: If you're expecting 10,000 images, it's the right way to do it.  If you're expecting more than 25, it's probably the right way to do it.

Comment: It's much faster and easier than first defining an array with 10k rows, and then retrieving a portion of it.

Comment: Sorry for responding so late. Anyways, I guess I'll make a database... hope the learning curve isn't too steep. Also, I thought caching was done automatically by the browser! Is there any where that gives easy tutorials regarding caching? Regarding your code, I just stick my huge block of php in there, right? Thanks in advance, by the way.

Comment: There are many levels of caching. Large scale web applications have caching implemented on multiple levels. There's cache at the database layer, data retrieval layer, html outputting layer etc... the caching I wrote is caching on a html-outputting layer - it will only make your script get run when it hasn't generated the cache file - if it has, it won't include your huge-array file, etc.. caching at the browser level is only about making sure that the user doesn't download the same images/css again and again and is also very important (but very unrelated to your question)